# Angular4 UrlSerializer for HATEOAS links in angular2 routing

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, hateoas

I'm fairly new to Angular4 and I'm trying to consume a HATEOAS API. Basically I want to pass either an object containing the self reference or the self reference link itself via the routing mechanism (e.g. click on an edit link in a list of objects). Unfortunately there aren't many tutorials or libraries for the HATEOAS client side where I could blatantly copy code.

I think this might be realizable with a custom UrlSerializer but I have no idea how to do that. I don't know how to serialize the object or link but still be able to find it later on. I'm happy for any suggestions that might bring me closer to a working solution, not necessarily using an UrlSerializer.

Basically I want the edit link to work like this (when account is a complex object):

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngfor="let account in accounts">
      <td>{{ account.username }}</td>
      <td>{{ account.password }}</td>
      <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/account', account]">edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does the info here help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696760/angular2-support-with-hateoas

Comment: Not really, I already have the links, basically I want to pass the "self" link to an editor component instead of an id (which I don't get from the API).

Comment: Do you have some code to show what you are trying to do or what you have tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I figured the best way to do this is by using a shared service that stores the reference links I'm trying to pass.

Comment: I am surprised that no one answered. I believe this is the way every applocation wou ld work as the ui should only follow links. Did u find another way of doing it besides servi es?

Comment: So far I haven't, but the probject isn't active anymore and I'd do a lot of things differently. Using ngrx basically made that problem not appear any more. Angular has come a long way in the last two years